# Google glass app distribution

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am developing Google glass app using GDK. I am aware that apk files can be installed in Google Glass using **adb tools**. But is there any other way to distribute the gdk apps, similar to **Google Play Store**?

**Notes:**

1. I have only GDK app and no mirror API app.
2. I have gone through https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/ and https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/update. But there is no sufficient information about how much time Google requires for testing and approval of submitted app and how to update next version(release)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://hockeyapp.net

HockeyApp may be one option for you

Comment: seems HockeyApp not supporting Google glass

Answer (score 0):

The *only* official Google Glass distribution channel is the [Glassware](https://glass.google.com/glassware/).
Submission details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/).
Unfortunately, the Glass team generally doesn't give any time frame...

Answer (score 0):

Since the Glass apps are still being tested and monitored regularly by Google, there is no fixed time frame for the same. You can always submit your app to the Glassware and post your suggestions on the [update form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/update).

Google Play Store only has the collection for Phone and Watch apps.